# Broken Desktop & unable to boot to fresh USB to reinstall.

Tags: boot, unity, login, compiz, lightdm

So, I have borked my Gnome-Session and don't really know what to do. I was trying to install some security tools because I am a computing security student in college. The SysLog shows something about compiz, but I have used a tty terminal to completely uninstall and purge ubuntu-desktop, lightdm, and compiz. With no avail, after I log into through the login screen I get the message shown below. I also have included a picture of the syslog. Also when I boot to a usb to just do a fresh install I get a white screen. I am running an old late 2008 MacBook.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/196za.jpg

Above are the images of the logs and the issues. I have commented them. Have tried everything if anyone has any ideas plz help :D

Comment: imgur.com/a/Lnqef That did not work, and neither did the first option. No errors were reported and ubuntu-desktop and unity were reinstalled but to no avail the same error message occurs. The "sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a" spat out "unknown option a". Wasn't sure what this does so I didn't really tinker. – sptfire127 1 min ago    edit

Comment: Could you please post text files and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter you can [save it to a file](/q/420981/175814) and use that. You might want to consult [How do I get information from the logs on my computer when I only have access to the command line?](/q/440087/175814) too. Thanks.